# How to remove web server in spring boot application and keep deploying into ecs with health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-pipeline

I have a spring boot service that send and receive messages only from a kafka topic,
I want to remove the web server (tomcat) since there is no need for it.
The problem is the service is currently deployed on ECS and the end point /actuator/health is used to check the health of the service, which means if I remove the web server the deployment in the pipeline won't be successful since the health checks will fail,

I tried making the ALB internal but the Kafka service is not in the same VPC and the service couldn’t connect

Is there any solutions to isolate the service ?

Comment: Change the healthcheck endpoint?

Comment: can you elaborate please ? @Riz

Comment: You can change your endpoint for the healthchecks on ALB. Instead of /actuator/health, do checks on a port which your application uses and you are sure if that port is not listening, it means your application is broken. Healthchecks are used to kow if your alb needs to route traiffic the the nodes or not. If you make healthchecks on let's say port 22 and your application is not running, still the traffic will be routed to your nodes. So the whole point of healthcheck is the traffic routing.

Comment: @Riz but the target group health check configuration supports only  HTTP/HTTPS traffic, it will send an HTTP GET request to the endpoint you specify and expect a response with code 200-399

Comment: You have Kafka pushing messages to the ECS servers, via the load balancer somehow?

Comment: Yes @Riz kafka is using other ports and TCP protocol to connect to the services in ECS